# add depth image to laser scan in a launch file

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

I'm trying to create my own .launch file but i can't understand how to add the follow rosrun to the file:

> rosrun depthimage_to_laserscan depthimage_to_laserscan image:=/camera/depth/image_raw

I know that I can run the node by typing

> 

but I don't know how to add the "image:=/camera/depth/image_raw" part.

someone can help me?

thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62990/add-depth-image-to-laser-scan-in-a-launch-file/) by [danielq](https://answers.ros.org/users/4679/danielq/) on ROS Answers with karma: 181 on 2013-05-17

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pallavbakshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/28889/pallavbakshi/) on 2017-01-27**:
@danielq - Can you post the launch file you created? I want to use depthimage_to_laserscan with kinect v2 and want to see how to use the parameters to use libfreenect2 driver with this package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

http://ros.org/wiki/roslaunch/XML

You're looking for the [remap](http://ros.org/wiki/roslaunch/XML/remap) tag.

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2013-05-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [danielq](https://answers.ros.org/users/4679/danielq/) on 2013-06-03**:
thanks a lot Dan, I followed the wiki and I have solved. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For the others, the answer is

```
<node name="depthimage_to_laserscan" pkg="depthimage_to_laserscan" type="depthimage_to_laserscan" > 
  <remap from="image" to="/camera/depth/image_raw"/>
</node>
```

---

Originally posted by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) with karma: 133 on 2014-08-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5